# How to add element to cell array including case it is empty?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Is it possible to add element to cell array including case when it is currently empty and or not exist?

All of these methods work

```
>> C={12}
C = 
    [12]
>> C=[C;13]
C = 
    [12]
    [13]
>> C{end+1}=14
C = 
    [12]
    [13]
    [14]
```

But all of them require `C` exists.

Neither work if `C` does not exist. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: not exactly the answer you are looking for, but a simple initial empty declaration `C={}` will make all of these methods work. As far as i know, you cannot _add_ an element to an array if it doesn't exist, but you can add element if it exists (=already declared), even if it is empty.

Comment: Check for its existence and create if not already present - `if ~exist('C','var'), C = {};end`? And then do whatever operation(s) you wish to.

Comment: @Divakar what if it exists, but of different type (normal array for instance)?

Comment: @Hoki why don't you post this comment as answer?

Comment: @SuzanCioc If it exists, check for the `class` and accordingly append data.

Comment: @Hoki if I do `C={}` I will loose data currently in `C`. I need to append data, i.e. conserve previous

Comment: @SuzanCioc. Sure that will erase anything previously existing in `C`. If you plan to use such a variable you declare it (_empty_) **at the very top of your code** (the very first time you mention it), then when you use it anywhere later in your code it is ready to receive newly added element.

Comment: If you are really worried it already exist then you can perform a check as Divakar described. (although if you suspect there are risks of variable telescoping themselves between different types, consider using longer, more meaningful variable names, to avoid risk of confusion and overwriting).